# convert react virtualized table from javascript to typescript - type issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-table-checbox-stackoverflow-rbl0v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js
And I put into my react project, and I am have problems with this piece of code:

```
 function _sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    const newList = _.sortBy(list, [sortBy]);
    if (sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC) {
      newList.reverse();
    }
    return newList;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
  function _sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }) {
    setSortBy(sortBy);
    setSortDirection(sortDirection);
    setSortedList(_sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }));
  }
```

### The variable newList has a weird type (see error below) and won't be accepted into the setSortedList function.
I have tried building an interface, but I am not sure how to make newList be that type.
Any tips for how to make this behave in typescript?

error

```
Argument of type '(number | { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; } | { <S extends { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }>(callbackfn: (value: { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[])...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }[]>’.

  Type '(number | { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; } | { <S extends { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }>(callbackfn: (value: { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[])...' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }[]’.

    Type 'number | { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; } | { <S extends { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }>(callbackfn: (value: { id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }, index: number, array: { ...; }[]) ...' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }’.

      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; code: string; title: string; status: string; assigned: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to declare the type for the two properties of the object which those functions take as their argument `({ sortBy, sortDirection })`.  If we were to call a sort function inline in the JSX then the arguments could be inferred from the component signature.  But when we externalize a function like this we need to tell it what arguments to expect since the function itself has no awareness of where it is called.

Hovering over the `sort` attribute on `Table` shows the arguments:

```
(JSX attribute) sort?: (info: {
    sortBy: string;
    sortDirection: SortDirectionType;
}) => void
```

Since we use this in two places, let's create a named alias for that object type:

```
interface SortInfo {
  sortBy: string;
  sortDirection: SortDirectionType;
}
```

Now we apply that type to our functions and everything works because the functions know the correct types for `sortBy` and `sortDirection`:

```
function _sort({ sortBy, sortDirection }: SortInfo) {
```

```
function _sortList({ sortBy, sortDirection }: SortInfo) {
```

[Fully Converted Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-virtualized-table-checbox-stackoverflow-forked-e2y45?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: thank you! is there a way to get around the "property index does not exist on type" error?

Comment: I included the `index` property on the `div` because it was there in the original code, but `index` is not a valid DOM property so I don't know why that's even there.  I think it still works if you just delete that property entirely?

Comment: well, i changed to have data-index, but when i run it and click the check boxes i get "cannot read property of "id" of undefined"

Comment: I would have to look at what the underlying package is doing with this `index` property and if there's a way around it.  If they are requiring you to use an invalid DOM property, that's a case when it's ok to suppress the error with `@ts-ignore`.  Although I tried `data-index` like you suggested and it seemed to work for me?

Comment: hmmm weird, i wonder if its some config i have or something, thank you again